# meaning of a pretty thing

Tags: meaning, grammaticality-in-context

“Nonsense, Grace, get in at once, and don't make all this fuss; **a pretty
thing** it would be if a man of business had to examine every cab-horse
before he hired it--the man knows his own business of course; there, get
in and hold your tongue!”

The above is from "Black Beauty" by Anna Sewell. (1877)

I think 'a pretty thing' in the above paragraph is a kind of twisted expression
and that's all, but I am not very sure of it. which means just an absurd thing or something.

Am I correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some words can be used ironically, examples are "fine" "grand" and "pretty".

> That's another fine mess you've got me into.
>   The train's been cancelled. Well that's grand.

"Pretty" is used here in the same way, to mean, ironically, "awkward" or "inconvenient".  It is a rather dated use of English, but Black Beauty is an old book.